# swift uitableview repeats first cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

Im a complete beginner to swift and iOS and I'm trying to write some code which will take some json and put it into an array of objects and then use that array to populate the tableview.
The problem is when I try to populate the tableview it just prints the first one so it looks like this: [image]

here is the code

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "comicCell", for: indexPath) as! ComicCell

    cell.title.text = comics?[indexPath.row].title
    cell.dateOnSale.text = comics?[indexPath.row].dateOnSale


    return cell
}
```

I tried to print the array of objects in a simple for loop and it works fine which led me to believe my problem is in the function above

Comment: It looks like you're mixing up `numberOfSections`  and `numberOfRowsInSection`. The former must return 1, the latter `comics.count`. And don't declare a data source array as optional.

Comment: @vadian Thank you very much! It works now

Answer (score 2):

The cellForRowAt method seems OK, I think you're having trouble with the **numberOfSections** and **numberOfRowsInSection** methods of *tableView*, the former must return *1* and the latter must return **comics.count** in your case.

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return comics.count
}
```